# Unable to install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu on both a Dell XPS 15z or a Dell XPS 8300.

Tags: installation, 64-bit

I have a Dell XPS 15z Laptop with an Intel Core i7, 6 GB ram, and an NVIDIA  graphics card.

I can install the 32-bit version of Ubuntu with no problems at all. But when I try to install the 64-bit version, as soon as I select the optical drive to boot from (e.g. cd/dvd) the screen goes blank apart from a flashing cursor and nothing happens.

I've tried booting from CD, DVD, USB, external harddrive and always the same problem.

I have a similar problem with my Dell XPS 8300 desktop. It is absolutely fine with the 32-bit Ubuntu but when I attempt to boot from cd it just goes straight into loading Windows.

I would like to install and use the 64-bit version of Ubuntu as I am processing very large genomic datasets.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 32-bit Ubuntu install CD which boots with no problem but the 64-bit does not boot, the most probable answer and first thing to check is if the 64-bit CD is faulty in some way.

Please take a look at the troubleshooting suggestions listed on the [**BootFromCD**](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD) help page.

In particular, open your 64-bit install media in any file manager. Does it look like the example below?

[image: screenshot of Windows Explorer showing contents of Ubuntu 12.04 install CD]

Answer (score 0):

I created a bootable usb drive to install the 32bit version, that is the only version on my computer at the moment. I don't even have any version of windows running on my computer. I don't have the 64bit version at all. My problem is with the 32bit. It will boot up to the login screen then once I login I have access to nothing, no files, no icons. It's just a blank screen.