# How to install 64 bit Ubuntu 15.04 on a 64 bit capable machine

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit

I have a laptop that is capable of running in both 32 and 64 bit modes:

```
$ lscpu 
Architecture:          i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2410M CPU @ 2.30GHz
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               800.000
CPU max MHz:           2301.0000
CPU min MHz:           800.0000
BogoMIPS:              4589.87
Virtualisation:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
```

However every time I try to install 64 bit Ubuntu it fails to boot from CD as described in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141596/unable-to-install-the-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu-on-both-a-dell-xps-15z-or-a-dell%22this%22) issue (a black screen). I have checked the contents of the CD and they seem correct to me:

```
$ ls /media/j1n3l0/Ubuntu\ 15.04\ amd64/
EFI                 boot    install     pics     ubuntu
README.diskdefines  casper  isolinux    pool     wubi.exe
autorun.inf         dists   md5sum.txt  preseed
```

Is there something fundamental I am missing? I would really appreciate any help in getting to the bottom of this.

Some system details:

```
$ uname -a
Linux j1n3l0-Ideapad-Z570 3.11.0-18-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 18 21:13:28 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What laptop model are u using, and which ubuntu version works?

Comment: I am using a Lenovo Ideapad Z570. All 32 bit versions of Ubuntu I have tried to install worked _(since 11.10 I think)_ but I have never managed to get 64 bit installed.

Comment: Have you tried the nomodeset kernel boot parameter ? like said in http://askubuntu.com/a/162076/350004

Comment: Was not able to. I only had a black screen to work with. In the end I managed to boot from the DVD (by pressing the -> key) but install failed. It seems I might have hard disk failures. Right now I have somehow ended up installing in OEM mode. Hopefully I'll get past the earlier failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled across a solution for this in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/575491) to a different question. Essentially virtualization was not enabled on my BIOS. Once I enabled that, I was able to get 64 bit ubuntu 15.04 on my laptop.